# Set SNMP community name on AWS Linux (centos)

Tags: security, snmp

I'm using AWS Linux (which is a Centos variant). I've used SNMP before. I'm trying to change the community name from `public` to `something1234` (for example).  I'm using the standard netsnmp package that one gets by running `sudo yum install snmp`.

My test to see if snmp giving me access control or not is to use snmpwalk. If this works, the community is public or is being ignored:

`snmpwalk -v 1 localhost -c public .1.3.6`

If that gives no output but this works, I'm golden:

`snmpwalk -v 1 localhost -c something1234 .1.3.6`

I have yet to be golden.

The distribution creates the file `/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf`.

The top of the file has this:

```
# First, map the community name "public" into a "security name"

#       sec.name  source          community
com2sec notConfigUser  default       public
```

I've tried changing `public` in that line to `something1234` but that doens't help. I've also tried adding this to the end of the file:

```
view    systemview      included .1.3.6.1.2
view    systemview      included .1.3.6.1.4
rocommunity something1234 localhost
```

That doesn't work either.

I've tried running `snmpconf` which is supposed to create and modify SNMP configuration files. It deletes my file `/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf` and creates a new file `/usr/share/snmp/snmpd.conf` which has a lot less information ... and which also doesn't work for `something1234`.

So how do I change the RO community to `something1234`?

Answer (score 0):

My snmpd.conf for recent versions of snmpd look like this.  Where the community would be `hunter`.

```
com2sec readonly default hunter2

group MyROGroup v1   readonly
group MyROGroup v2c  readonly
group MyROGroup usm  readonly

view all    included  .1  80
view system included  .1.3.6.1.2.1.1

access MyROGroup ""  any noauth exact all    none none

syslocation TheCloud
syscontact Zoredache <zoredache@example.org>
```

For snmpwalk you might need to use a command like this.

```
snmpwalk -c hunter2 -v 2c 192.0.2.5 -O n
```

Comment: wow. That is so easy. How come both the documentation and the sample config files make this so hard?

Comment: Not sure.  Debian ships with a default config that has the above.

Comment: Debian is amazing. I'm stuck using Amazon Linux, Centos and RHEL. But his worked just fine with those.